# Segmentation fault in __pthread_getspecific called from libcuda.so.1

Tags: c++, cuda, segmentation-fault

**Problem:** Segmentation fault (SIGSEGV, signal 11)

**Brief program description:**

- high performance gpu (CUDA) server handling requests from remote
  clients
- each incoming request spawns a thread that performs
  calculations on multiple GPU's (serial, not in parallel) and sends
  back a result to the client, this usually takes anywhere between 10-200ms as each request consists of tens or hundreds of kernel calls
- request handler threads have exclusive access to GPU's, meaning that if one thread is running something on GPU1 all others will have to wait until its done
- compiled with -arch=sm_35 -code=compute_35
- using CUDA 5.0
- i'm not using any CUDA atomics explicitly or any in-kernel synchronization barriers, though i'm using thrust (various functions) and cudaDeviceSynchronize() obviously
- Nvidia driver: NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  313.30  Wed Mar 27 15:33:21 PDT 2013

**OS and HW info:**

- Linux lub1 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- GPU's: 4x GPU 0: GeForce GTX TITAN
- 32 GB RAM
- MB: ASUS MAXIMUS V EXTREME
- CPU: i7-3770K

**Crash information:**

Crash occurs "randomly" after a couple of thousands requests are handled (sometimes sooner, sometimes later). Stack traces from some of the crashes look like this:

```
#0  0x00007f8a5b18fd91 in __pthread_getspecific (key=4) at pthread_getspecific.c:62
#1  0x00007f8a5a0c0cf3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#2  0x00007f8a59ff7b30 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#3  0x00007f8a59fcc34a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#4  0x00007f8a5ab253e7 in ?? () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#5  0x00007f8a5ab484fa in cudaGetDevice () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#6  0x000000000046c2a6 in thrust::detail::backend::cuda::arch::device_properties() ()


#0  0x00007ff03ba35d91 in __pthread_getspecific (key=4) at pthread_getspecific.c:62
#1  0x00007ff03a966cf3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#2  0x00007ff03aa24f8b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#3  0x00007ff03b3e411c in ?? () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#4  0x00007ff03b3dd4b3 in ?? () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#5  0x00007ff03b3d18e0 in ?? () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#6  0x00007ff03b3fc4d9 in cudaMemset () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#7  0x0000000000448177 in libgbase::cudaGenericDatabase::cudaCountIndividual(unsigned int, ...


#0  0x00007f01db6d6153 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#1  0x00007f01db6db7e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#2  0x00007f01db6dbc30 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#3  0x00007f01db6dbec2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#4  0x00007f01db6c6c58 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#5  0x00007f01db6c7b49 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#6  0x00007f01db6bdc22 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#7  0x00007f01db5f0df7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#8  0x00007f01db5f4e0d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#9  0x00007f01db5dbcea in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#10 0x00007f01dc11e0aa in ?? () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#11 0x00007f01dc1466dd in cudaMemcpy () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#12 0x0000000000472373 in thrust::detail::backend::cuda::detail::b40c_thrust::BaseRadixSortingEnactor


#0  0x00007f397533dd91 in __pthread_getspecific (key=4) at pthread_getspecific.c:62
#1  0x00007f397426ecf3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#2  0x00007f397427baec in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#3  0x00007f39741a9840 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#4  0x00007f39741add08 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#5  0x00007f3974194cea in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
#6  0x00007f3974cd70aa in ?? () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#7  0x00007f3974cff6dd in cudaMemcpy () from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0
#8  0x000000000046bf26 in thrust::detail::backend::cuda::detail::checked_cudaMemcpy(void*
```

As you can see, usually it ends up in `__pthread_getspecific` called from `libcuda.so` or somewhere in the library itself. As far as i remember there has been just one case where it did not crash but instead it hanged in a strange way: the program was able to respond to my requests if they did not involve any GPU computation (statistics etc.), but otherwise i never got a reply. Also, doing nvidia-smi -L did not work, it just hung there until i rebooted the computer. Looked to me like a GPU deadlock sort of. This might be a completely different issue than this one though.

Does anyone have a clue where the problem might be or what could cause this?

**Updates:**

Some additional analysis:

- `cuda-memcheck` does not print any error messages.
- `valgrind` - leak check does print quite a few messages, like those below (there are hundreds like that):

> ```
> ==2464== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 725
> ==2464==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==2464==    by 0x568C202: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ==2464==    by 0x56B859D: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ==2464==    by 0x5050C82: __nptl_deallocate_tsd (pthread_create.c:156)
> ==2464==    by 0x5050EA7: start_thread (pthread_create.c:315)
> ==2464==    by 0x6DDBCBC: clone (clone.S:112)
> ==2464==
> ==2464== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 725
> ==2464==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==2464==    by 0x568C202: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ==2464==    by 0x56B86D8: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ==2464==    by 0x5677E0F: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ==2464==    by 0x400F90D: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:254)
> ==2464==    by 0x6D23900: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:78)
> ==2464==    by 0x6D23984: exit (exit.c:100)
> ==2464==    by 0x6D09773: (below main) (libc-start.c:258)
>
> ==2464== 408 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 222 of 725
> ==2464==    at 0x4C29DB4: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==2464==    by 0x5A89B98: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5A8A1F2: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5A8A3FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5B02E34: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5AFFAA5: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5AAF009: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5A7A6D3: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x59B205C: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x5984544: cuInit (in /usr/lib/libcuda.so.313.30)
> ==2464==    by 0x568983B: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ==2464==    by 0x5689967: ??? (in /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0.35)
> ```

**More information:**

*I have tried running on fewer cards (3, as that is the minimum needed for the program) and the crash still occurs.*

**The above is not true, i misconfigured the application and it used all four cards. Re-running the experiments with really just 3 cards seems to resolve the problem, it is now running for several hours under heavy load without crashes.** I will now try to let it run a bit more and maybe then attempt to use a different subset of 3 cards to verify this and at the same time test if the problem is related to one particular card or not.

I monitored GPU temperature during the test runs and there does not seem to be anything wrong. The cards get up to about 78-80 °C under highest load with fan going at about 56% and this stays until the crash happens (several minutes), does not seem to be too high to me.

One thing i have been thinking about is the way the requests are handled - there is quite a lot of cudaSetDevice calls, since each request spawns a new thread (i'm using mongoose library) and then this thread switches between cards by calling cudaSetDevice(id) with appropriate device id. The switching can happen multiple times during one request and i am not using any streams (so it all goes to the default (0) stream IIRC). Can this somehow be related to the crashes occuring in pthread_getspecific ?

I have also tried upgrading to the latest drivers (beta, 319.12) but that didn't help.

Comment: This may be a bug in the drivers, CUDA or both. If this is the case, all you can do is try to make a repro code, send it to the NVIDIA bug report platform, and wait for an answer. They will tell you that you need to wait for the next CUDA release (5.5), and in the meantime, you may be lucky with the next drivers. The last bug I reported vanished with the current beta drivers (319.12), but I got two additional bugs, so... Still, I think you may be luckier if you post this on the NVIDIA forums.

Comment: @BenC: thanks, will try posting there too.

Comment: This could also be something else entirely, but NVIDIA developers should be able to provide some information that regular Stack Overflow users do not have.

Comment: Also, does `cuda-memcheck` return any useful error?

Comment: @BenC: provided some more info, please see above.

Comment: cuda-memcheck has a leak analysis tool, use `cuda-memcheck --help` for command line help.  Is it possible to reduce the number of GTX Titans in the system for test purposes?  Is it possible to replace the GTX Titans with a Tesla product for test purposes?  What sort of power supply do you have (must be pretty big)?  Can you monitor the GPU temps during a failure operation (`nvidia-smi` can help)?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: oh, I missed that feature of `cuda-memcheck`([its doc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#leak-checking)). Although, wouldn't CUDA return an "out of memory" error if memory leaking is the issue here?

Comment: Yes, it might return an out of memory error.  The cuda-memcheck leak analysis was just a suggestion for troubleshooting.  The leak info discussed in the OP's question (valgrind) is host-side leak, which is not what the cuda-memcheck leak analysis would be looking for anyway.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: i can (and will) try to test it with fewer cards, however i have no Tesla cards. The used power supply is: Enermax Platimax, ATX, 1500W. Also will try to see about the GPU temps and post an update here ASAP.

Comment: @BenC: Provided some more info. Still more and more convinced this might be really some driver/hw issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can identify 3 cards that work, try cycling the 4th card in place of one of the 3, and see if you get the failures again.  This is just standard troubleshooting I think.  If you can identify a single card that, when included in a group of 3, still elicits the issue, then that card is suspect.

But,  my suggestion to run with fewer cards was also based on the idea that it may reduce the overall load on the PSU.  Even at 1500W, you may not have enough juice.  So if you cycle the 4th card in, in place of one of the 3 (i.e. still keep only 3 cards in the system or configure your app to use 3) and you get no failures, the problem may be due to overall power draw with 4 cards.

Note that the power consumption of the GTX Titan at full load can be on the order of 250W or possibly more.  So it might seem that your 1500W PSU should be fine, but it may come down to a careful analysis of how much DC power is available on each rail, and how the motherboard and PSU harness is distributing the 12V DC rails to each GPU.

So if reducing to 3GPUs seems to fix the problem no matter which 3 you use, my guess is that your PSU is not up to the task.  Not all 1500W is available from a single DC rail.  The 12V "rail" is actually composed of several different 12V rails, each of which delivers a certain portion of the overall 1500W.  So even though you may not be pulling 1500W, you can still overload a single rail, depending on how the GPU power is connected to the rails.

I agree that temperatures in the 80C range should be fine, but that indicates (approximately) a fully loaded GPU, so if you're seeing that on all 4 GPUs at once, then you are pulling a heavy load.

Comment: @PeterK: If Robert's first test does not show any hardware malfunction for one of the cards, it may be wise to run another stress test on the system. If power consumption is the issue here, a highly demanding stress test should theoretically lead to the same problem. I do not know if there is any perfect tool for this (something like [this program](http://wili.cc/blog/gpu-burn.html) or [that one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cudagpumemtest/), perhaps?). If you experience the same problems with the stress test, you would know that your program is not faulty.

Comment: Thanks for the help. While i still do not know what is causing the problem i'm now in contact with NVIDIA engineers, so lets hope we will figure it out.